# Enviar un correo por PHP vía WEB funciona bien! Si uso ese mismo archivo usando la terminal no funciona

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Buenos días: Tengo el siguiente script de PHP para enviar un simple correo vía SMTP:

```
require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username ="h.dedios@countier.com.mx"; 
$mail->Password = "Horacio2016@"; 
$mail->setFrom('h.dedios@countier.com.mx', "Countier Uniformes");
$mail->addReplyTo('h.dedios@countier.com.mx', "Countier Uniformes"); 
$mail->addAddress('ivan@gmail.com','ivan@gmail.com');         
$mail->Subject = 'prueba';
$mail->msgHTML('prueba'); 
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error 1: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Este código lo visito en mi navegador, osea vía web y funciona perfectamente para enviar el correo, es decir que si lo envía.

Pero ahora si trato de correr el MISMO archivo por vía consola de comandos así:

```
php envioCorreos.php
```

entonces me marca que:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (61)

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Mailer Error 1: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

No encuentro por que si lo mando ejecutar por vía consola, marca que no se pudo conectar. ya trate de cambiar la línea $mail->Host = 'localhost'; por 127.0.0.1 o por la IP del servidor.
¿Alguna orientación? Gracias.

Comment: Qué se supone que tienes en el puerto 25? Y no asumas que localhost se resuelve como supones. Es posible que tu servicio SMTP esté oyendo cosas IPv4 y estés resolviendo IPv6, etc. En general, no es problema del script sino de la conexión, pareciera no estar disponible el servicio...

Comment: En la configuración de mi servidor web dice que el puerto 25 es el que debo usar para enviar correos por via SMTP... ese mismo archivo lo uso VÏA web y si envía los correos.

Comment: si ejecutas `php --help` veras las opciones disponibles creo que en tu caso sin los tags php deberia ser `php -r envioCorreos.php`

Comment: marca exactamente lo mismo. No se conecta